# How do I correctly markup a Product within an Offer within a Product?

Tags: javascript, schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I am getting Google Search console errors on the Product pages for a website I maintain, and I'm not sure how to resolve the errors.  The error I'm getting is:

> *One of **offers** or **review** or **aggregateRating** should be provided.*

This is simple enough to fix normally, however my confusion is that I am already providing the `offers` data in a different portion of the json ld.  The structure of my Product json ld is

```
Product{
    Offers{
        Product {}
        Product {}
    }
}
```

Where the nested products are the different variants of the same product.  I don't have reviews or ratings available on the site, so that leaves me with `offers` to resolve the error.  However google search console is saying that each of the nested products should have `offers` data, despite the fact that they are already contained within an offers structure.

This seems like it will dig down into an infinite loop: I add offers to the product variants, with an itemOffered type of Product, which will then require another offer, etc.

How can I organize my structured data to both support my product -> variants hierarchy, while also pleasing google search console and removing the errors I'm seeing?

Here's the full JSON ld that you can directly copy/paste into the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/) to see the exact issue I'm describing.

```
{
   "@context":"http://schema.org/",
   "@type":"Product",
   "name":"Stripe Knit Sweater",
   "url":"http://foobar.gov/product",
   "image":[
      "http://foobar.gov/product/image1"
   ],
   "description":"this is a description",
   "brand":{
      "@type":"Thing",
      "name":"My Store"
   },
   "offers":[
      {
         "@type":"Offer",
         "availability":"http://schema.org/InStock",
         "price":"64.0",
         "priceCurrency":"USD",
         "url":"http://foobar.gov/product/url",
         "itemOffered":{
            "@type":"Product",
            /*ERROR IS HERE! : One of offers or review or aggregateRating should be provided.*/
            "image":"http://foobar.gov/product/url",
            "name":"Small / Blue/Black/Cream Stripe",
            "weight":{
               "@type":"QuantitativeValue",
               "unitCode":"lb",
               "value":"0.0 lb"
            },
            "url":"http://foobar.gov/product/url"
         }
      },
      {
         "@type":"Offer",
         "availability":"http://schema.org/InStock",
         "price":"64.0",
         "priceCurrency":"USD",
         "url":"http://foobar.gov/product/url",
         "itemOffered":{
            "@type":"Product",
            /*ERROR IS HERE! : One of offers or review or aggregateRating should be provided.*/
            "image":"http://foobar.gov/product/url",
            "name":"Medium / Blue/Black/Cream Stripe",
            "weight":{
               "@type":"QuantitativeValue",
               "unitCode":"lb",
               "value":"0.0 lb"
            },
            "url":"http://foobar.gov/product/url"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: try using https://schema.org/ProductModel for level 2 products. That `@Type` may not a mandatory relationship with the property `aggregateRating` and will convey the same meaning you assert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example it seems that each `Offer` is a variant of `Product`. If that's the case, I'm not sure nesting `Product` inside of a variant would be needed. As far as I can tell from your example the only property in the nested `Product` which is unique is `weight`, which you could apply to `Offer` using `additionalProperty`.

If sent this way to the tool everything will validate:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name":"Stripe Knit Sweater",
  "url":"http://foobar.gov/product",
  "image":[
      "http://foobar.gov/product/image1"
  ],
  "description":"this is a description",
  "brand":{
      "@type":"Thing",
      "name":"My Store"
  },
  "offers": [
      {
          "@type": "Offer",
          "availability":"http://schema.org/InStock",
          "price":"64.0",
          "image":"http://foobar.gov/product/url",
          "name":"Small / Blue/Black/Cream Stripe",
          "priceCurrency":"USD",
          "url":"http://foobar.gov/product/url",
          "additionalProperty": {
              "@type": "PropertyValue",
              "name": "Weight",
              "unitCode": "1b",
              "value": "0.0lb"
          }
    },
    {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "availability":"http://schema.org/InStock",
        "price":"64.0",
        "image":"http://foobar.gov/product/url",
        "name":"Medium / Blue/Black/Cream Stripe",
        "priceCurrency":"USD",
        "url":"http://foobar.gov/product/url",
        "additionalProperty": {
            "@type": "PropertyValue",
            "name": "Weight",
            "unitCode": "1b",
            "value": "0.0lb"
        }  
    }]
}
```

[Googles Schema Documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product) on `Offer` states that `itemOffered` is a recommended field and that it's "typically a product", but doesn't have to be. It's also worth noting that contrary to the documentation, the tool does not warn you if `itemOffered` does not exist in `Offer`

Even though [schema.org](https://schema.org/Offer) provides `itemsOffered` as an option unfortunately there is no example of that with nested `Product`s.

Nesting `Products` or `Services` could make sense in the following scenarios:

- (Product) Salon Package

  - (Offer) Nail/Massage Combo

    - (ItemOffered)

      - (Service) Nail polishing and Neck Massage

or:

- (Product) Sweater

  - (Offer) Blue Sweater

    - (ItemOffered)

      - (Product) Blue Sweater

        - (Offer) Blue Sweater on Amazon - $49
        - (Offer) Blue Sweater on eBay - $39
  - (Offer) Red Sweater
    ...

Either way, I think the expectation makes sense here, the `Product` in any scenario will eventually end with `Offer`. In your case, I believe the fix would be to not use nested `Product`s only to describe the `Offer`.