# Invalid structured data (offer) since Google Update : one of offers or review or aggregateRating should be provided

Tags: google-search, schema.org, json-ld

I have the following piece of structured data :

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Offer",
  "priceCurrency": "EUR",
  "price": "12890",
  "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
  "priceValidUntil": "2019-12-13",
  "itemOffered": {
    "@type": "Car",
    "brand": {
      "@type": "Brand",
      "name": "Renault"
    },
    "manufacturer": {
      "@type": "Corporation",
      "sameAs": "https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q6686",
      "name": "Renault"
    },
    "name": "Renault Captur Life",
    "model": "Captur Life",
    "image": "https://www.xxxx.fr/uploads/models/renault-captur.png",
    "description": "Renault Captur Life neuve - Essence - 90cv - 5 portes : 12 890€ ",
    "fuelType": "Essence",
    "vehicleTransmission": "Manuelle",
    "vehicleConfiguration": "0.9 tce 90 bvm5",
    "numberOfDoors": "5",
    "vehicleEngine": {
      "@type": "EngineSpecification",
      "enginePower": {
        "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
        "value": "90",
        "unitCode": "N12"
      }
    },
    "itemCondition": "https://schema.org/NewCondition"
  }
}
```

According to [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/), there is a problem (this is a recent update, my structured data used to be valid):

> One of offers or review or aggregateRating should be provided.

According to the [Rich Snippets Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results), it's valid.

So what's going on here? Why should I have to add `offers` or `review` or `aggregateRating`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Tony's answer, `Offer` should be an extension of `Car` (`Product`). `Product` can be nested within `Offer` ([see this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738927/how-do-i-correctly-markup-a-product-within-an-offer-within-a-product/58871460#58871460)) but that doesn't look like what you want here.

Modifying your JSON-LD to this will make things valid (as far as [Googles Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) is concerned):

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Car",
  "fuelType": "Essence",
  "model": "Captur Life",
  "name": "Renault Captur Life",
  "description": "Renault Captur Life neuve - Essence - 90cv - 5 portes : 12 890€ ",
  "vehicleEngine": {
      "@type": "EngineSpecification",
      "enginePower": {
          "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
          "value": "90",
          "unitCode": "N12"
      }
   },
   "manufacturer": {
       "@type": "Corporation",
       "sameAs": "https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q6686",
       "name": "Renault"
   },
   "image": "https://www.xxxx.fr/uploads/models/renault-captur.png",
   "vehicleTransmission": "Manuelle",
   "vehicleConfiguration": "0.9 tce 90 bvm5",
   "numberOfDoors": "5",
   "brand": {
       "@type": "Brand",
       "name": "Renault"
   },
   "offers": [{
       "@type": "Offer",
       "price": "12890",
       "priceCurrency": "EUR",
       "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
       "priceValidUntil": "2019-12-13"
    }],
    "itemCondition": "https://schema.org/NewCondition"
  }
}
```

In this scenario, we nest the `Offer` in `Car` so that `Car` describes everything about the vehicle and the nested `Offer` describes how it can be purchased.

I'd note that as of this writing the [Rich Snippets Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) is still in beta so I'd take its results with a grain of salt. You could argue since it is a new tool, it might be more in tune with what Google does with Rich Snippets.. but in your case here I believe the expectations from the Structured Data Testing Tool make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The change caused that error to go out when people have structured their data in your way. i.e. the offer as the main entity. If you flip your markup around so it is a product with an offer the error should go away. Both ways are valid, the the second one is in line with Googles examples and what their testing tools report on.